# return lists in perl cause different results

Tags: perl, list, return

```
my @names =  ( (), 'my', 'name' );

sub fn1 {
    my @names =  ( 'my', 'name' );
    return ( (), @names ); #<<< this must be flatted
}

sub fn2 {
    return ( (), 'my', 'name' );
}

say length fn1();  #1
say length fn2();  #4
say length @names; #1
say length scalar ( (), 'my', 'name' ); #4


say scalar fn1(); #2
say scalar fn2(); #name
say scalar @names; #2
say scalar ( (), 'my', 'name' ); #name

# but this produce same output
say fn1();  #myname
say fn2();  #myname
say @names; #myname
say ( (), 'my', 'name' ); #myname
```

Why in subroutine fn1 variable @names does not flatted and array instead of list is returned?

It seems that perl return two lists: one is empty and second is array @names.

This list of two elements in scalar context return last element - arrray.

Array in scalar context is its length: number 2

lenght of string '2' is 1, **but this is differ from fn2**

Is there any possibility to flat @names in fn1?

Comment: I add empty list to flat @names. I can rewrite: change please empty list in both functions to string 'arg1'.  I use empty list only to not change list values. I want get same list.

Comment: @Schwern: I expect that earlier. but now I understand 'why' it is not flattening. See my answer below

Comment: I was wrong, `()` is doing something.  I've been using Perl for 20 years and I've never come across this use of `()`!  Impressive!  I've updated my answer to explain what's going on and where our confusion was and why you should still stop using it.

Comment: My code is useless, I ask just to know what is going on and not to use this.

Comment: My code is useless, I ask just to know what is going on and not to use this. But I go to perldoc and see BUG at documentation. Relaying on our conclusion **map** MUST NOT be documented as: returns the list value composed of the results of each such evaluation. In scalar context, returns the total number of elements so generated. Actually map always returns an array and in scalar context returned array is evaluated to size. Other wrong thing is that, if I generate more elements: `map { ( $_, $_) } @array`. Here is OK,

Comment: BUT generating empty elements `map { ((),$_) } @array` return wrong value in scalar context. Because of I generate two times more elements, but `scalar map { ((), $_) } @array`, return only half of them. So saying in documentation that: map **always** returns the array of values composed of the results of each such evaluation. Will be OK. Also there must be revised sort, grep etc. For example. Why we limit sort in scalar context? if sort return list, so evaluatint thist list in scalar context must cause last element have been returned relaying on list behaviour/documentation

Comment: The important part of the map documentation I think you're missing is that it "*evaluates BLOCK or EXPR in list context*". That means regardless of what context the map is in, the block will still be run in list context.  `map { ((), $_) }` will be flattened to simply `map { $_ }`.  To think of it another way, `$c = map { ... } @a` is equivalent to `@m = map { ... } @a;  $c = @m;`  The docs can always be clearer, and sometimes they do have mistakes, but not this time.

Comment: No, I mean return value of map

Comment: Responding to "*map always returns an array and in scalar context returned array is evaluated to size*", that is not true.  The map documentation is correct, "*In scalar context, returns the total number of elements so generated.*"  If you look at the code for map (which is also grep), and I apologize it's not easy to understand, [it checks the context and will only return the number of elements in scalar context](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pp_ctl.c#L1073).  As for sort in scalar context, its behavior is undefined and what it should do is an old, unresolved question.

Comment: is the paranthes () element generated?  In return ((), @names) it is

Comment: Asking if an empty list is generated doesn't make sense in Perl.  `()` is a red herring.  What you're seeing is the list vs scalar behavior of [the comma operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator). In scalar context it returns the right argument (`@names`), `()` is just a placeholder for the left argument, try putting anything else there and you'll see.  In list context comma is the list element separator and `(), @names` is flattened to just `@names`.  A `map` block is *always evaluated in list context*.

Comment: returning to my example: return ( (@names) , () ) in scalar context will return element (). So relying on "In scalar context, map returns the total number of elements so generated", I expect that `map ( (), $_ ) @array` will generate two elements per step.

Comment: In list context, `()` flattens to nothing.  It's not an element of a list.  The list `(1, 2, 3, ())` has three elements, `()` does not count.  If you want to put an empty list in a list you need to use a reference to an empty list, `[]`.  `(1,2,3,[])` has four elements, the last is a reference to an empty list.  The map block/expression is *always evaluated in list context* so `map { (), $_ }` will flatten to `$_` and return a single element per step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html

If I really want to return **array** (NOT LIST) from subroutine, regardless of calling context I must write:

```
return @{ [ @names ] }
```

instead of

```
return ( (), @names );
```

becase calling function fn1 in scalar context really mean:

```
return scalar ( (), @names );
```

I must look description of **return** operator: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html

**Evaluation of EXPR may be in list, scalar, or void context, depending on how the return value will be used**

More detailed description from Schwern:

In scalar context, `return( @name )` says "evaluate this array in scalar context" and returns the number of elements. In list context it will return all of @names. Simple. This is what you want to be using.

`return( (), @names )` on the other hand is the **comma operator**. In list context it will return the whole list which flattens to @names. In scalar context it will return the last element, which is @names, which will then be evaluated in scalar context returning its number of elements.

To see how this is true, if we add another element onto the end that's what we get back.

```
sub foo { return (), @names, 42 }
print scalar foo;    # 42
```

Comment: `return @{ [ @names ] }` and `return @names` are equivalent (with some slight differences if `@names` is tied or an overloaded object but don't worry about that right now) except the former wastes memory by copying the whole array. *Hold up, I'm wrong about `()` having no effect.  You still don't want to be using that construct. You want to learn about return contexts.*

Answer (score 5):

In case there's confusion, `length` does not return the number of elements in the array.  It returns the size of a string.

What you're getting caught out by is the [list vs array problem in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?).  In short, an array is a variable like `@array`.  A list is something like `(1,2,3,4)`.  The problem comes when Perl evaluates them in scalar context.

An `@array` in scalar context will return its number of elements.  A list in scalar context acts like the C comma operator, it returns its last element.

```
$ perl -wle 'sub foo { @a = ("first","second"); return @a } print scalar foo()'
2

$ perl -wle 'sub foo { return("first","second") } print scalar foo()'
second
```

So when you try `sub foo { return("first","second") } print length foo()` `length` puts the call to `foo()` in scalar context.  `foo()` treats the list in `return("first", "second")` as the comma operator and returns the last element returning `"second"`.  And you get 6.

```
$ perl -wle 'sub foo { return("first","second") } print length foo()'
6
```

Long story short, ***don't return lists***, return arrays.

**UPDATE**: I've figured out your confusion, and my own.  `()` is doing something, it's converting what should be a simple array into a C comma operator.  `return( (), @names )` and `return( @names )` are not the same thing.  Let's pick them apart.

In scalar context, `return( @name )` says "evaluate this *array* in scalar context" and returns the number of elements.  In list context it will return all of `@names`.  Simple.  This is what you want to be using.

`return( (), @names )` on the other hand is the **comma operator**.  In list context it will return the whole list which flattens to `@names`.  In scalar context it will return the last element, which is `@names` which will then be evaluated in scalar context returning its number of elements.

To see how this is true, if we add another element onto the end that's what we get back.

```
sub foo { return (), @names, 42 }
print scalar foo;    # 42
```

Part of what's going on here is `return` is not acting like a normal function.  It does not squash its arguments into an array before acting on them.  You are returning the literal evaluation of the expression `(), @names, 42` which is the comma operator.

I can see now why you started using `()`, but all you are doing is forcing the expression to be evaluated as the comma operator.  Stop using it, it's a crutch and it's very hard to understand.  What you need to do instead is [learn about return contexts](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558).

My very strong rule of thumb remains, don't return lists, return arrays.

Comment: To clarify your last point, you mean don't return lists _in scalar context_, correct? Isn't it perfectly reasonable for functions to return lists when `wantarray` is true?

Comment: @SamChoukri It's a rule of thumb (and yes, it's return arrays instead of lists).  If you're checking `wantarray` you should already know enough about context and the list vs array problem else you're just going to shoot yourself and everybody around you in the foot.  However, as I progress I find myself less and less designing functions which diverge from array behavior in list vs scalar context.

Comment: @Schwern: may I use part of your answer?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Sure.  What for?

Comment: to put into my answer. your description is better. but whole answer is too broad, i think

Answer (score 2):

[length](http://p3rl.org/length) and [scalar](http://p3rl.org/scalar) force scalar context, while [say](http://p3rl.org/say) forces list context.

Note that the lengths match the strings:

```
String  Length
--------------
2        1
name     4
2        1
name     4
```

Comment: That is only half of what is going on here.  There's a list vs scalar problem as well.

Comment: @Schwern: I didn't want to repeat your reply :)